# How can I match an .npmrc file with gulp.src?

Tags: node.js, gulp, glob, minimatch

I've been trying to use a glob in gulp.src to match all files, including dotfiles, and specifically `.npmrc` files. I've tried the following patterns;

`gulp.src('/path/to/my/files/**/{*,.*}')`

`gulp.src('/path/to/my/files/**/*', {dot: true})`

`gulp.src('/path/to/my/files/.npmrc')`

None of those patterns worked. More details can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1523).

Does anyone know why `.npmrc` files aren't being matched by these patterns? Does anyone know how to match them?